# Where does the source code of evdev free the memory of "struct evdev" in linux version 3.4?

Tags: embedded-linux, evdev

I'm tracing the evdev's memory in linux version 3.4.
I find a memory is allocated in function "evdev_connect", and the allocated memory size is according to "struct evdev".
The problem is I can't find where the memory is free?
I think this memory should be free in "evdev_disconnect", but I can't find the related code.
Even the evdev's source code has "evdev_free" function, but it doesn't be called.